# How to add build script and tests in NodeJs project

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, build

I have created a basic todo app which has `package.json` file as:

```
{
  "name": "to-do-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A basic to-do app created using JavaScript.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Sahil Silare",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "build": "^0.1.4",
    "ejs": "^2.7.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "npm-build": "0.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/sahil9001/to-do-app.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "todo",
    "app"
  ],
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/sahil9001/to-do-app/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/sahil9001/to-do-app#readme"
}
```

Whenever I run `npm test` it fails by saying no tests specified, how can I solve this issue? also whenever I try to use `TRAVIS CI` it fails to detect `build` script how can I create one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify all required script in scripts property in package.json as below

```
{
      "name": "to-do-app",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "A basic to-do app created using JavaScript.",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "put test command here",  // example "test": "mocha test.js"
         "build" : "put build command here"
      },
      "author": "Sahil Silare",
      "license": "MIT",
      "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "build": "^0.1.4",
        "ejs": "^2.7.1",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "npm-build": "0.0.1"
      },
      "devDependencies": {},
      "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git+https://github.com/sahil9001/to-do-app.git"
      },
      "keywords": [
        "todo",
        "app"
      ],
      "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/sahil9001/to-do-app/issues"
      },
      "homepage": "https://github.com/sahil9001/to-do-app#readme"
    }
```

You don't have any scripts command listed in scripts property and have only default. You have to create and place it as per the need. Refer below links for more details

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/introduction-to-npm-scripts-1dbb2ae01633/

https://flaviocopes.com/package-json/

Comment: What are tests and how can I build one?

Comment: @SahilSilare It seems you are a beginner in development. The question that you asked is a broad topic. Never mind, Learn development, you will be able to figure out on your own. you can refer this : https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/learn-nodejs-unit-testing-in-nodejs/

Comment: Yeah, I've just started with dev, thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

If you look under "scripts" you'll see your npm scripts such as the script you call when you run "npm test"

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

The default value when you run NPM init is this simple echo saying no tests, you have to write your own test command(s) here.

Travis is failing to detect a build script, because you don't have a value for "build" in your scripts section, add something like:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "my_script_to_build"
  },
```